# How to define a recursive data type that refers to its definition

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures

I want to write a data type to evaluate the expressions like this:

`a` is evaluated to `a`

`a + b * c / d -e`  is evaluated to  `a + (b * (c / (d - e)))`

So the first argument is always a number and the second one is either a number or an expression

I have tried to define a data type like this

```
 data Exp  = Single Int
          | Mult (Single Int) Exp
```

But it gives me this compilation error:

```
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Single’
    A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
  |         
9 |           | Mult (Single Integer ) Exp 
  |
```

I can define it like this:

```
data Exp  = Single Integer
          | Mult Exp  Exp
```

But it does not give the precise definition of the Type I want.
How can I define this?

Comment: `But it does not give the precise definition of the Type I want.` What is the type you want then? Your first version fails because `Single a` is a value, not a type. The second one looks correct to me, if it differs from what you need then please explain what the difference is. (Well if you want it polymorphic it should be `data Exp a = Single a | Mult (Exp a) (Exp a)`)

Comment: `Single a` is not a type. You can either define it as a `Mult a Exp`, or `Mult Expr Expr`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  in this case `Mult a Expr` is closest to what I want. I was thinking, How can I tell compiler that the first argument should be a specific definition, instead of `Mult Exp Exp`

Comment: What's wrong with `data Exp = Single Int | Mult Int Exp`?

Comment: @DanielWagner Nothing, except we do not have `Mult Int Exp` in the language, I'm trying to evaluate. It has 'Mult Single Int Exp' . The next best option is `Mult Exp Exp` , but it allows `Mult Exp (Single Int)` which is illegal.

Comment: @Ali What is the difference between what you want `Mult (Single Int) Exp` to mean and what `Mult Int Exp` actually means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it does not give the precise definition of the Type I want.

`Single a` is *not* a type. `Single` is a *data constructor*. So `Single a` does not make much sense.

You can use `Exp` here as first parameter, or if you want to restrict the first operand, you can use:

```
data Exp a = Single a | Mult a (Exp a)
```

Indeed, since `Single a` just wraps an `a`, you can use an `a` as first parameter of `Mult`. The `Mult` data constructor context, makes it clear how to interpret that `a`.

If you want to allow multiplying two `Exp a`s, then you can define this as:

```
data Exp a = Single a | Mult (Exp a) (Exp a)
```

You can use [*generic abstract data types (GADTs)*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) to make finer specifications when two expressions can be multiplied.

Comment: You are write, but I want somthing like this: `data exp a = Red a | Blue a | Op (Red a) Exp`, How can define it?

Comment: @Ali: You can not do that, or at least not directly, you can however define some extra types, and use `GADT`s to enforce constraints. For example `newtype Red = Red`, `newtype Blue = Blue`, `newtype Op = Op` and then `data Expr a b where; Red :: a -> Expr a Red; Blue :: a -> Expr a Blue; Op :: Expr a Red -> Expr a c -> Expr a Op` for example.